# How to get string as Y output using Linear regression Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have this rating prediction model using linear regression

```
status = pd.DataFrame({'rating': [10.5,20.30,30.12,40.24,50.55,60.6,70.2], 'B': ['Bad','Not bad','Good','I like it','Very good','The best','Deserve an oscar']})

x = status.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = status.iloc[:,-1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,train_size=0.4,random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x,y)

input = 40.24
lr.predict([[input]])
```

So I have 40.24 as my input for X value I was expecting for 'I like it' as the output but it throws error instead because the expected output is a string, here's the error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Bad'`. How do I make it capable of having string as output?

Comment: Wait a minute your running a regression model, but your doing a classification problem, i think you choose logistic regression instead and apply the following at the answer i have given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi thats because sckitlearn or rather machine learning labels require numbers as an input, i am not sure what the classes are in this case but you can use the [onehotencoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder) from sckitlearn

Also do change it to logistic regression

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# 1. INSTANTIATE
enc = OneHotEncoder()

# 2. FIT
enc.fit(y)

# 3. Transform
onehotlabels = enc.transform(y).toarray()
onehotlabels.shape

clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(x, onehotlabels)
```

or you can just manually map it out which ever way you prefer
(e.g Bad -> 0, Good -> 1)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do a `Linear Regression` if you have `Target feature as a Categorical D-Type`.
That is the first rule of performing a Linear Regression that you should have Continuous Target feature as the `y=mx+c` function only takes in numbers as input and tests the function against the numerical items and predicts the numerical item.

> That is why it gets trained but fails to predict.

You need to encode your target feature.
Please self-study these concepts.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your labels are categorical where regression labels should be continuous numerical.
You can consider to see it as a classification problem rather than regression.